# Creating a JAVA database from code. Statement wont execute and create table?

Tags: java, sql, database, database-connection, derby

I'm not sure why my program isn't creating the table but I also need some ideas on how to fill the table with code like this once it's created? I need to add two more tables to this database too.

This is the error I'm getting :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'PIZZASIZE' does not exist.
Caused by: ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'PIZZASIZE' does not exist.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: file:/C:/Users/Allie/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Pizzeria_AllieBeckman/dist/run1674141987/Pizzeria_AllieBeckman.jar!/pizzeria_alliebeckman/FXMLDocument.fxml
```

This is the code that's supposed to create the table:

```
        // connect to the derby URL using the given username and password
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pizzeria;create=true", connectProps);
        // current url for pre created database "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pizza"
        // if connection is successful print that it succeeded.
        System.out.println("database created");

        stmt = connect.createStatement();

        String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE PIZZASIZE "
            + "(id int NOT NULL, "
            + "size char(20) NOT NULL, "
            + "PRIMARY KEY (id))";

        stmt.execute(sqlCreate);
```

Comment: try `stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCreate)`

Comment: Same error with stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCreate) :(

Comment: `System.out.println("database created");` this is executed?

Comment: yes that does print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the IDE you are using you could manually create the table in a console without going through the trouble of writing it in code. Here are some examples of how you could get the information from the tables.

```
Connection conn = CreatingDerbyDJB.dbConnection();

            try{
                String query = "INSERT INTO  Items (Name,Color,ItemName,SchoolName, Description) VALUES(?,?,?,?, ?)";
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);


                pstmt.execute();
                conn.close();
              }catch(Exception e)
            {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }       }
```

Here is what the Connection class should look like:
package main;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CreatingDerbyDJB 
{
    public static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    public static final String JDBC_URL  = "jdbc:derby:LostAndFoundDB";
    public static Connection dbConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
            return c;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Approve this answer if this helped you, I'd be happy to explain things if it does not make sense.  :)

Comment: Thanks, this is good information! The prepared statement is working to create a table but I can't seem to populate it and I'm a little confused by the "setString(x, xxx)" method. I only need the ID and "size" column in the table and it'll only have 4 options in it.

Comment: To populate the table you have to use an insert into query as if you were working with a regular database programming language. You would insert it based on the name of your table then list the columns in parenthasis. and then you specify the values you would want to be inserted. Also, sorry about the setString that was code from my program I forgot to delete lol